# Print server PS310U and Printer standby mode

Tags: printer, print-server

I am experiencing an annoying behavior with my Tp-Link PS310U print server.

I have connected it to a Samsung C430 printer, which is a USB laser printer. Actually, everything works fine as long as the printer goes into sleep mode.

If the printer is directly connected to the USB, then just by sending to it another printing job it wakes up and start printing.

If the printer goes into sleep mode once connected to the PS310U print server, then the only way to recover the system is to reboot the print server.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Do I have to disable the sleepmode?

Answer (score 0):

[Solved] I have found that the printer was going in timeout mode. This implies that the priter shuts doen itself. In that case only an external user can reactivate the printer. This behavior makes the print server to crash. By disabljng the timeout option on the printer solved the issue